# linq to sql submitchanges rollback

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, rollback

is there a way to roll back after a db.submitchanges without de need of transactions?

It would be a shame having to run a service special for loggings. Is there an alternative to roll back and not to use that special service?

thanks in advance!

EDIT:

What I really want: I have 2 database interactions I want to do right after each other.

let's say, I want to add something in database table 'Slots'. After submitting this, I can receive the Id, which has been created by the auto-increment.

That Id, I want to use to insert a new log in the database. but when inserting into the logs fail, I want to rollback the action in 'Slots' too..

this is possible with transactions I believe, but it seems I'm not able to do this without getting errors. even when all servers are set to allow them and firewalls are off..

Comment: What special service are you talking about? What about the logging? I'm unclear what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

No.

`db.SubmitChanges()` is opening a transaction itsself so avoiding it is not an option.

Not sure what you mean with loggin service, I guess you mean that you use the database for logging and you are using the same datacontext for writing the log to your database and your business-data so it can happen that your business data fails (so Rollback of the transaction) and also your logging is rolled-back.

The easiest solution is to use a speparate datacontext for your logging.

**Update**
There is no need for multiple SubmitChanges in your case because you do not need the ID, you can add the entity to the log. Have a look here
[How do I get Id of a record without submitting and re-querying?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12728643/)

And since you can have only on SubmitChanges, it will all be in one transaction and it will do exactly what you want

Comment: Answered that already in a different question - I updated my answer with a link

Answer (score -1):

You should insert both the Slots and the log at the same time.

i have no idea of how your data model is build up but simplified.

```
Log myLog = new Log();
Slot mySlot = new Slot();
...
...

DataContext db = new DataContext();

db.Slots.InsertOnSubmit(mySlot);

myLog.Slot = mySlot;
myLog.... = ....;

db.Logs.InsertOnSubmit(myLog);

db.SubmitChanges();
```